# navigate through cmd to a folder that starts with P_

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I have a problem.

I have a script where i want to move one File (here it starts with S_) to a folder, which always starts with P_.

It is the only folder in the directory, where i wanna move it to, but when i go like

```
move "C:\Temp\Test\S_*" "C:\Move\New\P_*"
```

It creates a new file in *C:\Move\New*, but i want it to be in the only folder which starts with P_.

Hope you get it. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` to expand wildcards:

```
for /d %x in (C:\Move\New\P_*) do set dest=%%x
```

This will set the `%dest%` variable to the directory you want; use the variable with `move`.

(This would normally loop over *all* matching files – or folders with `/d` specified – and would end up setting `%dest%` to the last item. When you have only one matching item, it'll of course be the last one.)

Comment: Do i write this command before the move line or after? Im pretty new :D

Comment: Scripts run from top to bottom; if you want to use a command like `move C:\Something "%dest%"`, then %dest% must be _already_ set at that point, therefore the 'set' command that sets %dest% must be above the 'move' command that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Move\New\P_Full_Name" && move "C:\Temp\Test\S_*" .
```

---

**1.** Enter the destination folder using the full path name:

```bash
cd /d "C:\Move\New\P_Full_Name"
```

---

**2.** Using the `&&` operator will execute the `move` command only if the `cd /d` command returned success, otherwise ignore the `move` command:

```bash
cd /d ... && move ...
```

---

**3.** When you are in the `target` folder (`cd /d` command returned success), then the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) will recognize the current folder as target "`.`" in the `move` command:

```bash
move "C:\Temp\Test\S_*" .
```

---

- **Obs. 1:** The `move` command and/or the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) will not translate/interpret the wildcard "`*`" to compuse the full name to target.

---

- **Obs. 2:** To loop through multiple folders with names starting with **`P_`**:

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Move\New\" 

for /d %%i in (P_*)do cd /d "%%~fi" && =;(
      2>nul move "C:\Temp\Test\S_*" . 
    );=
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /D /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143) // Also applies to `cmd.exe`
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Hello, Point 3 really helped. :) 

Its pretty simple and now i learned something new. :) Thanks a lot!